# SourceTree y GitHub Desktop copiar y pegar codigo mostrar todo el código modificado y eliminado

Tags: github, sourcetree, github-desktop

Hola estoy utilizando [SourceTree para desktop](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) y [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/).

En SourceTree puedo ver las lineas que se modifican y se eliminan por cada `commit` pero no puedo hacer un `copy and paste` me muestra el codigo pero solo las partes que se han modificado ¿Hay alguna forma que te muestre todo el código de esa clase y te pinta en rojo lo que se ha eliminado y en verde lo que se ha agregrado y hacer un `copy and paste` a estos códigos? Les dejo un gif del source tree no se puede hacer `copy and paste` del código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado he probado GitHub Desktop y si se puede hacer `copy and paste` del código y en settings hay una opción `hide whitespace settings` que te permite mostrar toda la clase y en verde te marca lo agregado y en rojo lo eliminado. Les dejo un gif del GitHub Desktop.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer en [SourceTree para desktop](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) lo que se puede hacer en [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)?

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Miguel, procura agregar "," a tu texto ya que no se entiende bien, lo que deseas es poder copiar el código agregado y eliminado que se muestra en el archivo?

Comment: Hola Jorge, si quiero hacer un `copy and paste` del código que se muestra en el source tree y que se muestre toda la clase no solo las partes agregadas, modificadas y eliminadas. Que se muestre toda la clase y que ahí este resaltado con rojo lo eliminado y con verde lo agregado y que ahí se pueda hacer el copy and paste se puede hacer GitHub Desktop pero no es SourceTree.

Comment: Ok , agregué una respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de `SourceTree` no tiene una opción pero en este caso se debe usar una herramienta externa que previamente debes instalarla, puedes configurarla en `Tools` > `Options` > `Diff`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en mi caso uso https://winmerge.org/ , al seleccionar la utilería solo debes seleccionar la aplicación en el directorio donde esta instalada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al estar configurada selecciona "External Diff" desde `SourceTree`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma puedes ver tanto el código que agregaste como el que se eliminó:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]